# Patching: Replacing a method call with another

Tags: python, unit-testing, patch

I use Python's mocking framework for tests - It works great!
However, one thing I wasn't able to figure out, is how to patch a function so that I replace the call with another function.

Example:

```
# module_A.py
def original_func(arg_a,arg_b):
    # ...

# module_B.py
import module_A

def func_under_test():
    # ...
    module_A.original_func(a,b)
    # Some code that depends on the behavior of the patched function
    # ...

# my test code
def alternative_func(arg_a,arg_b):
    # do something essential for the test

def the_test():
    # patch the original_func with the alternative_func here
    func_under_test()
    # assertions
```

Usually the assertions are enough, but in this case I need the `alternative_func` to kick in instead of the `original_func` right when it is called.

Also notice that `alternative_func` requires the same arguments.

I'm sure it's super easy, and mayb it is the late hour, but I just don't see it...

Answer (score 4):

in your test `import module_A` at the top and then in your setup function use:

```
module_A.original_func = alternative_func
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the original function so you can restore once you're done with the test function:

```
import module_a

def the_test():
    orig_func = module_a.original_func
    module_a.original_func = alternative_func

    # do testing stuff

    # then restore original func for other tests
    module_a.original_func = orig_func
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the original to point to the new

```
original_func = alternative_func
```

Then calling original will actually call alternative